# Examples or datasets of evolving networks

Tags: data-request, network-structure

I'm a master student working on networks analysis in general. A network is something that has nodes and there are links between the nodes. Nodes and links could have attributes. An evolving network is one that changes overtime (new nodes and links are added..etc). An example of that is Facebook. Nodes are users and links represent the friendship relationship. Users have attributes (gender, age ..etc). A Facebook network as you know is an example of a social network.

The issue is that so many people studied traditional evolving networks like social networks, the web, or transportation networks. Currently I'm looking for novel examples of evolving networks to study them.

I'm aware of `snap.stanford.edu/data/` but all of those datasets were heavily studied. So I thought maybe someone is aware of novel datasets that represent evolving networks?

If you know some novel datasets or maybe could think of some novel examples for an evolving network dataset that I could construct, I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: Cross-posted (well, sort of) to Earth Science SE

Comment: @DeerHunter yes i'm considering all fields

Comment: I'd recommend studying something that is interesting to you. If you expand on your interests than maybe OD can help.

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite (dynamic) networks to study is Wikipedia. You have plenty of data to analyze and it is evolving every second :)

Here is an example of the edits in Wikipedia articles: http://rcmap.hatnote.com/#en

However, if you want more options, [in this repository](http://www.growmeme.com/snas), you will find dozens of networks and you could sort the table by "Dynamic" networks to find only those you need.

Answer (score 1):

I've not looked at this myself, but I found online at the University of California in Irvine they have a repository of network data for study.

*The UCI Network Data Repository is an effort to facilitate the scientific study of networks. Feel free to browse and download the currently available datasets. For more information about networks and the terms used to describe the datasets, click Getting Started*.

http://networkdata.ics.uci.edu/resources.php