# Dataset for temporal community detection

Tags: data-request, network-structure, time-series

I want to test my overlapping community detection method in a dynamic network and I need a dataset consist of time series which every snapshot shows network in a specific time. But network should have group structure. Is there any dataset with these features? Also is there any benchmark (such as LFR benchmark for static networks) produces dynamic network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thought would be to look at the bioinformatics world, specifically looking at metabolic networks in developmental biology or something like that.

http://www.devbio.biology.gatech.edu/?page_id=11223

Things like phage lambda are the simplest networks (see book, "A Genetic Switch"), then you can go to bacteria (E. coli), eukaryotes (yeast, S. cerivisiae), slime molds (dicty), then multicellular. There is a lot of network information out there but it may have some overhead.

This question may be very similar:
[Examples or datasets of evolving networks](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/2115/examples-or-datasets-of-evolving-networks?rq=1)